# Is it possible to display a different version of a Site Page in SharePoint 2016 for certain users?

Tags: 2016, sitepages

I have some users who would like their site page to look different for them, versus what everyone else sees (certain links are different, etc). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Site home page configure a script editor web part... where write a code to get the logged-in user, then write if condition something like below to redirect to separate site page for that user. You can use the below javascript function:

**Redirect the specific user to a different page:**

```
function RedirectSpecificUserToDifferentPage()
 {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        context.load(currentUser);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    }

    function onSuccess(sender, args)
    {
        var userLoginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
        If(userLoginName =="Your specific user name ") 

        {
         var url= "https://yoursite/sites/sitepages/your_site_page_for_the _dedicated user.aspx"; 
        window.location = url; 

        } 


    }

    function onFail(sender, args)
     {
        alert('Failed to get current user' + args.get_message());
    }
```

Note:

If you are using SharePoint Online, you can directly use the  **_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName** global variable to get the logged-in user login name.